# Return transaction's ITEM column from QB

Tags: quickbooks

I created a small c# WCF app, which is to run on a computer with QB installed and return 
data. My GetCustomerTransaction web method calls QBFC
RequestSet.AppendTransactionQueryRq() and RequestSet.AppendTxnDeletedQueryRq().
Boss now says :) give me values of ITEM column in QB transaction grid.
(Examples: "Assessment", "Late Fee")
I don't find this field returned in my QBFC calls result set.
Is TxnLineID field what I need ?
Which QBFC query to add to get ITEM's value (ItemQuery ?)

Thanks,

Vlad

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this information from a `TransactionQuery` request.

Use a request specific to the type of object you're trying to get data for. For instance, if you're trying to get item data off of an Invoice, then use an `InvoiceQuery`. If you're trying to get item data off a Sales Receipt, use a `SalesReceiptQuery`.

You'll need to specify `<IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>` to make sure you get the line items for those transactions back.

Comment: Thanks, I am not a bookeeper, so do I understant you right that depending on TxnType of TransactionQuery I should do some more specific query ?

Comment: Yes. Or ask the boss what type of transaction you should be searching - he will probably tell you it's an invoice, and then you would only have to do an InvoiceQuery and not have to do a TransactionQuery at all.

Comment: Boss wanted Item and Desc fields which I found in Stmt Charges only :) So I added AppendChargeQueryRq() (together with AppendTransactionQueryRq()) and found matching charges by TxnID. Seems to be working. Thanks again.

Comment: If you only found those fields in Statement Charges, you didn't look in the right places. They also exist for Items, Invoices, Sales Receipts, Sales Orders, Estimates, Purchase Orders, Credit Memos, and Bills.